# JS Некорректное вычисление процента схожести значений списка

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции

Есть у меня код который выдаёт насколько в списке разные числа...
то есть при массиве [1,1,1,1] он выведет 100%
[1,9,1,9] - 81% и так далее...но я столкнулся с проблемой,что если использовать большие числа на подобие 50 или выше сотни то проценты уходят в минус...причём очень большой...например [1,9,1,99] выведет -1614.75 с чем это связано я понять не могу...помогите пж
P.S.использование кода:

```
similarity([1,1,1,1]);
```

сам код:

```
expectancy(arrayOfValues) {
        let sumTotal = function(previousValue, currentValue) { 
            return previousValue + currentValue; 
        };
        let u = arrayOfValues.reduce(sumTotal);
        u = u / arrayOfValues.length;
        return u;
    }
    similarity = function(arrayOfValues) {
        let sumTotal = function(previousValue, currentValue) { 
            return previousValue + currentValue; 
        };
        let u = this.expectancy(arrayOfValues);
        let sig = [];
        let N = 1/arrayOfValues.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfValues.length; i++) {
            sig.push(N*(arrayOfValues[i] - u) * (arrayOfValues[i] - u));
        }
        sig = sig.reduce(sumTotal);
        return 100 - sig;
    }
```

UPD:спасибо за ваши ответы,проблему решил...
Рабочий код:

```
singleSimilarity(a,b) {
        return a >= b ? b/a*100 : a/b*100;
    }
    similarity(arrayOfValues) {
        var j = 0;
        for (let i = 1; i < arrayOfValues.length; i++) {
            j+=this.singleSimilarity(arrayOfValues[i],arrayOfValues[i-1]);
        }
        return j/arrayOfValues.length;
    }
```

Comment: а вы простым языком не хотите пояснить, что вы считаете схожесть, и как вы ее вычисляете?

Comment: и почему бы там не быть -1600 ? формально, у вас никаких процентов тут нет. вы берете мат.ожидание `u`. считаете сумму ряда `N*Sum (a[i]- u)^2`, и вычитаете эту сумму из 100. У вас же нет никакой нормировки этой суммы к 100, никто не мешаете ей быть больше или меньше?

Comment: А какой должен быть правильный ответ для `[1,9,1,99]` и почему?